# Hibernate Criteria Cast with Projections

Tags: java, hibernate, casting, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a criteria with two projections, both sums. The result is restricted by some Id, so it is one row only. I want the result to be a list of doubles.

something like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SomeClass.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", id))
                       .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                          .add(Projections.sum("aFloatColumn"))
                            .add(Projections.sum("anotherFloatColumn")));
```

I want the result to be an array or a list.

Doing this way:

```
Object result = (Object) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

The result is a single object with value "[sum1, sum2]";

When I try to cast it to Double[] or List< Double > I get java.lang.ClassCastException. That's because the result is a single object with a single value which is a tuple.

Any Ideas?

Obs.: I can handle the object to do what I want. Turn it to String, split, cast... But I think that there must be a smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with two consults:

```
    setProjection(Projections.sum("aFloatColumn"));
    List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();
    result.add((Double) criteria.uniqueResult());

    setProjection(Projections.sum("anotherFloatColumn"));
    result.add((Double) criteria.uniqueResult());
```

If anyone know how to do it with a single shot, let me know. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have cast the result to `Object[]` (it would return you an array of object containing two `Double`s, in your case); then each element of the array could have been cast separately.